# User Info endpoint not finding openid scope

Tags: c#, identity, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am configuring my implementation of IdentityServer3 to be an Identity Provider to a new client application (Salesforce Communities) using the AuthorizationCode flow. Everything is working as expected until the client hits the userinfo endpoint, at which point the following errors occur:

```
ERROR IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenValidator Checking for expected scope openid failed
```

and

```
ERROR IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpointController insufficient_scope
```

This obviously leads one to believe that the client did not request the openid scope in the authorize request, which is required when using OpenId Connect. However, I can confirm that the client does indeed request a scope of openid in the authorize request:

```
INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "{client_id}",
  "ClientName": "{client_name",
  "RedirectUri": "{redirect_uri}",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "{allowed_uri_which_matches_request}"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "{subject_id}",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid",
  "State": "{state_value}",
  "SessionId": "402a2356f0bd91a350dfd1f8779ea229",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "{client_id}",
    "redirect_uri": "{redirect_uri}",
    "scope": "openid",
    "state": "{state_value}"
  }
}
```

I can also confirm that openid is an allowed scope for my client, and that openid is in the ScopeStore.

Furthermore, when I look at the tokens being generated in the database, they all correctly have the openid scope. There is just something in that userinfo endpoint that is causing the check to fail.

I am utterly perplexed by this issue as the implementation of this client is almost entirely standard and out of the box. If it will help, I can provide the complete logs of all three requests: authorize, token, and userinfo.

Thank you!

Comment: The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-delimited, case-sensitive strings. May be like: "scope": "{ openid }"  or String[] scopes = new string[] { "openid" };

Comment: Yes I can confirm that a scope of "openid" is being passed by the client during the authorize request. I have tried adding other values like "openid profile" and I still get the same error about the openid check failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being in a custom override of the DefaultClaimsProvider, specifically in the GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync method. The method was manually assembling a list of the claims to add to the token, and conveniently ignoring the scope claim for openid. How our previous implementations ever worked without this claim is beyond me, but after adding it back in everything worked smoothly.